# Humidity Level for Bamboo Flooring

Tags: flooring

What are appropriate humidity levels for bamboo flooring post-installation? I've heard that most hardwoods are good between 35-50% humidity but have been unable to locate anything specific to bamboo.

Comment: Humidity level for what? During installation? Where to keep the humidity in the room after installation? As far as I know the only recommendation is the same as other natural wood flooring, and that's to let the wood equalize in the room for a few days before installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search found me this web page:

http://www.bamboo-flooring.com/bamboo-floor-maintenance.html

> 14 Maintain relative humidity. Using a dehumidifier or humidifier to maintain relative humidity in the home at 30-50% will maintain the moisture level in the wood and help minimize cracks between the boards. Continued excessive humidity can cause swelling of the floor. Continued lack of humidity (below 20%) can cause shrinking of the planks and/or cracking of the bamboo strips.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just say if your in a humid erea then bamboo is then exactly what it is. Here is a link because it can be tricky to understand it.

http://www.bamboohardwoodflooring.net/